# Retrieve all item in listbox and select only those which is in db

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, listbox

Using first method I'm setting default subjects in listbox and using second I'm retrieving only these who was selected.

```
public void SubjectsList()
    {
        ViewBag.Subjects =
            new SelectList(new[] { "Math", "Physic", "English" }
            .Select(x => new { value = x, text = x }),
            "Value", "Text");

    }

    public void SubjectsFromDb(int id)
    {
        var students = _db.Subjects.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.StudentId == id).Select(q => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = q.Name,
            Text = q.Name,
        }).ToList();
        ViewBag.Subjects = students;
    }
```

How can I do that in Listbox was all Subject but selected were only these which is in db?

Here's my listbox

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Subject, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.Subject,
         new MultiSelectList((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Subjects, "Value", "Text"),
                    new { style = "display:block;" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Subject)
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: It just needs to be `ViewBag.Subjects = new SelectList(new[] { "Math", "Physic", "English" });` There is no need for the extra overhead of creating anonymous objects :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke ok will improve that. Can you help me with problem?

Comment: Sure, can you confirm that property `Subject` is `IEnumerable<string>`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke It's `List<string>`

Comment: @GiorgiPilishvili instead of List<string> try string array

Comment: @GiorgiPilishvili check this https://dotnetfiddle.net/sHo9qF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model property `Subject` needs to be `public IEnumerable<string> Subject { get; set; }` although I would suggest it be renamed to `Subjects` - plural) and you rename the `ViewBag` property

The in the GET method, assign the existing subjects to the model

```
var model = yourModel()
{
  Subjects = _db.Subjects.Where(x => x.StudentId == id).Select(q => q.Name);
};
ViewBag.SubjectList = new SelectList(new[] { "Math", "Physic", "English" });
return View(model);
```

Then in the view its

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.Subjects, (SelectList)ViewBag.SubjectList)
```

Side notes:

1. There is no need for the extra overhead of creating anonymous
   objects to generate the `SelectList` - you can delete `.Select(x => new { value = x, text = x }), "Value", "Text")`
2. Since its already a `SelectList`, there is no need for the extra
   overhead of creating another duplicate `SelectList` in the
   `ListBoxFor()` method

Comment: @unique - what are you trying to say? `string[]` is `IEnumerable<string>`

Comment: Just another side note: Your code suggests your database structure is probably wrong. You should have a  table `Subjects` with `ID int` and `Name varchar` and a table `StudentSubjects` with `ID int`, `Student int` (FK to Students table) and `Subject int` (FK to Subjects table)

Comment: @unique, You have not solved anything. The values from the database are **not** selected in the listbox. Study my answer and learn :)

Comment: @Stepen yes you are true but this context I "just" said he can also use string[] ok.

Comment: @unique, You could use `string[]`, or `List<string>` or `IList<string>` or `IEnumerable<string>` - it does not matter, so long as it **is** `IEnumerable<string>` which is what they all are